# How to get from Toronto Downtown to Pearson Airport

Tags: public-transport, canada, toronto, yyz

I am staying in downtown Toronto (near the Church/Adelaide St crossing). I will have to catch a national flight from Pearson Airport (YYZ). The flight is leaving at a proper time (around noon) on a weekday. How can I effectively (quick, cheap) get from downtown Toronto to YYZ by public transportation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a number of choices:

- [Take the TTC](http://www.ttc.ca/Riding_the_TTC/Airport_service.jsp). For example, subway to Kipling (west end of line 2, transfer from line 1 at St George), then "rocket" bus line 192 to the airport. It will cost you $3.00. You may not enjoy dealing with your luggage and you may have to change a bit, eg streetcar to subway, change subway at Yonge/Bloor, then subway to bus.
- [Take the Airport Express](http://torontopearson.com/en/toandfrom/downtownexpress/Downtown_Express/#). Hurry, because it stops running Oct 31 2014. This bus has power and wifi. If you can get yourself to one of its stops, it will be the most convenient. It costs a little under $30.
- Wait until [the UP express](http://www.upexpress.com/en/information/information.aspx) opens (spring of 2015 they say) and take that instead. Price is said to be "competitive" though with what, I don't know.

You can also take a cab or a limo but they will not be cheap. You can get an idea of fares from [the airport site](http://torontopearson.com/en/toandfrom/taxilimo/#).

Answer (score 7):

The [UP Express Train](https://www.upexpress.com/) will take you from downtown Toronto (Union Station) to Pearson International Airport "in 25 minutes".  Currently, a one-way adult ticket is $12 CAD.

Some lesser-known, but good-value fares are:

- "Meeter and Greeter Return" ($12 CAD)

> Guests meeting travellers at the airport may purchase this return ticket at a reduced fare.
>   Trips must originate from Union, Bloor and Weston stations only.
>   Fare expires within 4 hours of your trip start time.

- "Long Layover Return" ($12 CAD)

> Guests with long flight layovers can purchase this return ticket at a reduced fare.
>   Valid from Pearson Station only.
>   Fare expires within 7 hours of your trip start time.

Comment: I would like to add that the second option is, in my opinion, the best (cheapest, quickest, most convenient) way to get downtown to see a sporting event at either the Rogers Centre or the Air Canada Centre for someone based outside of the city; especially if you can get someone to drop you off/ pick you up at the airport.  Both venues are within walking distance of Union Station.  Even after a lengthy baseball game, there is usually still time for a sit-down meal at a restaurant, allowing you to meet the 7-hour fare window.

Comment: Note that this service wasn't yet in operation at the time the question was originally asked.  But it's still good to update old questions as conditions and available services change.  +1.